# how to perform regex for password validation without special character?

Tags: regex

Regex for password of minimum length-7 without special characters , atleast one uppercase and one number .

In my case, regex which satisfies:

**Killer1 - atleast one uppercase (K), atleast one number (1) , minumum length - 7**

**Melbourne123- valid**

**London24 - valid**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: `^(?=\w*([A-Z]\w*[0-9]|[0-9]\w*[A-Z])\w*).{7,}$`

Comment: Hi thomas @ThomasAyoub i am very new to web development. I understand you point.But i had no other go to find how a regex can be built for a condition so i posted.

Comment: Thanks for ur response.@horcrux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Minimum length 7

This part is unsurprisingly the simplest. You can just use:

```
.{7,}
```

In order to perform the other checks in a single regex, you need to make use of [look-aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as follows:

> at least one upper-case

```
(?=.*[A-Z])
```

> at least one number

```
(?=.*\d)
```

> without special characters

**I would strongly advise against this requirement** if at all possible. Adding this does not improve your security, and will only frustrate your users. But, if you really must, then:

```
(?!.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])
```

(Modify the above as appropriate -- depending on what exactly you mean by "special" characters.)

Putting this all together into a single pattern, the final answer is:

```
\A(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{7,}
```

You could also simplify this regex slightly, by merging the "no special chars" and "minimum length" requirements into a single regex condition as follows:

```
\A(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}\z
```

(Note the additional use of a `\z` anchor here, in order to check that *all* password characters are in the whitelisted "non-special" characters.

Comment: Thanks tom. It cleared the scenario